# Remove value duplicates in Multimap

Tags: java, android, multimap

I have a Multimap and I need to display the output like this:

> key (value count)

For example, I have these data inside the Multimap:

```
{Entertainment=[5],
Food=[2, 2, 2],
Products=[11],
Health & Beauty=[3]}
```

The number in the array is the ID of related keys.
What I would want it to output is as follows:

```
Entertainment (1)
Food (3)
Products (1)
Health & Beauty (1)
```

Of course, I want the ID to be carried along as well.

This is what I did so far,

```
Multimap<String, String> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();

for (int i = 0; i < response.getMerchants().size(); i++) {

    //hmm.setCategory_id(response.getMerchants().get(i).getCategory_id());
    //hmm.setCategory_name(response.getMerchants().get(i).getCategory_name());
    //hmm.setCategory_count(123); // FIXME

    map.put(response.getMerchants().get(i).getCategory_name(),
    response.getMerchants().get(i).getCategory_id());

    //arrCategory.add(hmm);
}

for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    int count = map.get(key).size();

    Log.d(TAG, "count= "+count);
}
```

Just so you know, the value will be put in an array an passed to the `BaseAdapter` to populate a ListView. Or is there any other way to do this besides using Multimap? I've used `HashMap<String, String>` before, but it removes duplicate.

If anything unclear, please let me know. I've done thinking about it.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this problem by using HashMap instead.

In a for loop,

```
Map map = new HashMap();

...

map.put(response.getMerchants().get(i).getCategory_name(),
   response.getMerchants().get(i).getCategory_id());

...
```

To put it in my adapter:

```
for (Object o : map.entrySet()) {
    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) o;
    HomeMerchantsModel hms = new HomeMerchantsModel();
    hms.setCategory_id(String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
    hms.setCategory_name(String.valueOf(entry.getKey()));

    arrCategory.add(hms);
}
```

Since HashMap stores unique key-value, this is useful. Now moving on to calculate the counts.